# React / JSX: Rendered <script> Tag Adds Equals Sign and Quotes to async Attribute

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I made a simple web app with Next.js / React.  One of the functional components (Next.js "page") returns some JSX that includes a  tag like

```html
<script async src="https://example.com/file.js"></script>
```

However, when I look at the page source of the rendered page, I see the `async` is instead rendered as `async=""`.  Is there a way to force the attribute/tag to be rendered verbatim instead of adding the equals sign and quotation marks?  Either for this particular tag, or in general?

Edit: Here is a minimal JSFiddle which shows the undesirable behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/1vbnms3j/ .  This is evidently just a React / JSX issue, unrelated to Next.js.  I have tried solutions such as https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9230#issuecomment-388118729, but none of `async=''`, `async={true}`, `async={undefined}` seem to work.  Also doesn't make a difference whether I use `<script></script>` or `<script />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an ugly solution that works:

```html
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `</script><script async src="https://example.com/file.js"></script><script>`,}}/>
```

This renders my tag correctly (the `async` attribute is displayed correctly and in the right position), but generates unnecessary `<script></script>` before and after my tag (although those are mostly harmless).

I'd still like a cleaner solution that does not generate unnecessary tags, if possible.

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11624

Comment: Yep.  In my use case I had an external script which was checking for the presence of (exact string match) something like `<script src="magic.js" async></script>` in my page's source code, so I needed to have `async` not `async=''`.  But I think the upshot is that there is not a clean official solution for this and some hack like the above is probably necessary, in the absence of someone making a react PR.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue yesterday. The discussion on that issue link says async="" is also a valid way to write it so _async_ or _async=''_  doesn't really make a difference !? This I haven't tested it yet though but if it is so then we should be good with any.

Comment: What counts as valid HTML is different than what an algorithm might be expecting to find in your source code.  If an algorithm is literally trying to string match "<script async>" in your code, then "<script async=''>" will not match, even though the latter is perfectly valid HTML.